# How to use input from same textbox for different buttons?

Tags: c#

I have two buttons. One for Sign In and one for Sign Out. I requires the input of a name and pin. The sign in button works but the sign out button does not work. I am not sure what is wrong.

Sign in button:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int pin = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string name = textBox3.Text;
            Employee Daniel = new Employee("Daniel", 5741);
            if (name == "Daniel")
                {
                Daniel.OnSignIn(pin);

            }
```

Method for OnSignIn

```
public void OnSignIn(int input_pin)

{

if (input_pin == pin)
{
    this.start = DateTime.Now;
    MessageBox.Show("You are logged in!");


}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Pin");

}
```

Sign Out Button:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int pin = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string name = textBox3.Text;
            Employee Daniel = new Employee("Daniel", 5741);
            if (name == "Danel")
            { Daniel.OnSignOut(pin); }
    }
```

OnSignOut Method:

```
public void OnSignOut(int input_pin)
    {

        if (input_pin == pin)
        {
            this.end = DateTime.Now;
            this.hours_worked = end.Subtract(this.start);
            this.total_hours += this.hours_worked.Seconds;
            MessageBox.Show("Logged Out! You have worked for" + this.hours_worked.Seconds + "for this session. " + "You have worked " + this.total_hours + "seconds in total.");
            this.SignIn = false;

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Pin");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the error? Without that, it's hard.

Anyway, check if you condition is right: In **SignIn** you compare `name == "Daniel"`, in **SignOut** you compare `name == "Danel"`.